# Build Select List with a PDO query as choseable options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, pdo

I want to create a Select List, which lists items/information from a Query. Its necessary to update the select list everytime I've updated the db so I have to use JQuery for it. I have never used JSON so I'm really bad and unexperienced with it.

I want to output the fields "email" and "balance" for every option in the select list like this:

```
<option>john@doe.com - 120020</option>
<option>john2@doe.com - 130020</option>
```

**My HTML Selectlist:**

```
<select id="assignaccount" name="assignaccount" class="form-control select">
    <option>Database</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
    <option>Option 4</option>
    <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

**My Ajaxrequest:**

```
function buildSelectList(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/database/accounts.php",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(data.id);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

**My "database/accounts.php"**

```
function selectPlayerless(PDO $db){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT accountId FROM PlayerCards)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**My problem:**
I have no idea how I should realize the Ajax Request this way, that it loops thru all Rows and adds the necessary fields as option into the select field.

Comment: side note - use either `dataType: "json"` or `var data = JSON.parse(response);`, not both.

Comment: So you just need help with taking the `response` in `success: function (response)` and adding it to `<select id="assignaccount" name="assignaccount" class="form-control select">`?

Comment: thats right, as long as the database/accounts.php is also fine for that. Thank you for your side note, changed that.

Comment: just create an ajax request which also sends the one you selected inside the select box, that must also be included with the request

Comment: Ghost I want to fill this select list by information which I select via the SQL query above. I think you missunderstood my question.

Comment: @kentor if you want that, then either get the json response then build the markup client side, or build the markup in the server then send it as a response and directly place the markup after receiving it.

Comment: Yeah the theory ive got as well, but as described I dont know how I can relize the loop thru and adding option elements to my select. I would be really thankful for an answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, since you explicitly put `dataType: "json"`, you do not need `JSON.parse`.

Second, just build the markup after receiving the response from the server:

Rough example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/database/accounts.php",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        var opt = '';
        // loop the response
        $.each(response, function(i, e){
            // just use your column names, these are just an example, but you get the idea
            opt += '<option value="'+e.id+'">'+e.email+'</option>';
        });
        // append the markup to that select box
        $('select#whatever_this_selectbox_is').html(opt);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Sidenote: I suggest use `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, since you really don't need to values in numeric indices.

Comment: Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ALL' <-- whats the reason for this when I try to use it as you suggested ?